# Vue/Nuxt set $nextTick or setTimeout to call a function in a specific page

Tags: vue.js

I'm try to call a function every 10 seconds on my page, on mounted, but when i visit the page and i leave it, the function continue to run.

```
mounted() {

       if(this.user_authenticated) {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                window.setInterval(() => {
                    this.updateValuePage();
                },10000);
            })
        }
}
```

if i leave the page, the function continue to run. How i can stop or use it only in that page and not globally ? I've also tryed to created() but same problem. The function is in page itself, not in mixin or plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You need clear the interval using [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

```js
let internal;
export default {
    mounted() {
       if(this.user_authenticated) {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                interval = window.setInterval(() => {
                    this.updateValuePage();
                },10000);
            })
        }
    }, 
    beforeDestroy() {
        clearInternval(interval);
    } 
}
```